# how to get nav menu list through menu name in wordpress

Tags: menus

How to get nav menu list through menu name in WordPress

I'm using this code by this code but showing all pages not working with custom nav menu name

```
<?php wp_page_menu('sort_column=ID&amp;sort_order=desc;'); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) function, which deals with the navigation menus that you create in the WordPress admin (*Appearance > Menus*)

You can call it like this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Header Menu' ) ); ?>
```

Where `Header Menu` is the name of the menu you want to print. There are other parameters [available](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu).

Comment: Did my solution work for you, @javeednizar?

Comment: I know this is kind of old, but that will return a 500 error (as of the date of this comment). You'll need to wrap the key => values inside an array: `wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'menu_name') );`

Comment: @stinkysGTI good catch, thanks. Not sure how it's been wrong for so long.